# Android app to create .txt file

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to create an app where a user selects a few checkboxes, then when they hit submit it creates a .txt file with a sentence in it for every checkbox selected.

I have had one successful build of this, and it created the file properly, but I need it saved to an accessible file location so that it can be attached to an email.  I don't really care where it saves to, as long as it is accessible.

The following code causes a crash when run in Android Virtual Device and my Galaxy 2.  The application is a proof of concept for a later app.   Thank you.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             String nochartOutput = " ";    
             if (sitting.isChecked())
                 nochartOutput += "The patient was sitting in a chair. ";
             if (breathing.isChecked())
                 nochartOutput += "The patient was breathing. ";
             if (alert.isChecked())
                 nochartOutput += "The patient was alert. ";

             FileOutputStream fOut = null;
             File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             try {
                 fOut = openFileOutput(sdDir + "/AutoWriter/samplefile.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
             try {
                 osw.write(nochartOutput);

                 osw.flush();
                 osw.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
```

> 03-04 18:39:53.604: W/dalvikvm(10453): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c211f8)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /mnt/sdcard/samplefile.txt contains a path separator
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1703)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:723)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:165)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at com.example.com.dresdor.autowriter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>
> 03-04 18:39:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you add the errors in logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing code is a mashup of writing to internal storage and external storage.  The line

```
fOut = openFileOutput(sdDir + "/AutoWriter/samplefile.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

attempts to create a file in the app's private data directory, and you can only pass file names to this method, not a deeper path.  That's where the crash is coming from, but it's not what you want.

You started to create a path to external storage, but never actually used it.  To write the file to that location on the external SD card, modify your code like so:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
//Since you are creating a subdirectory, you need to make sure it's there first
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AutoWriter");
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs();
}

try {
    //Create the stream pointing at the file location
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory, "samplefile.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

//...etc...
```

Using the SD card allows the file to be accessed by anyone.

Answer (score 2):

openFileOutput() writes file in the internal memory and not sd card. So change

```
fOut = openFileOutput(sdDir + "/AutoWriter/samplefile.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

to

```
fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Also the file name can not contain path separators. See [Android Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

*public abstract FileOutputStream openFileOutput (String name, int mode)*

> Open a private file associated with this Context's application package
>   for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.
>
> Parameters name   The name of the file to open; **can not contain path
>   separators**.

The file can be then be accessed like this.

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("samplefile.txt");
```

**Note:**
For files which are huge in size, it's better to save it in sd card. Here is the code snippet.

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AutoWriter");
        if (!rootPath.exists()) 
            rootPath.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(rootPath, "samplefile.txt");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // ... more lines of code to write to the output stream

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to write file on external storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does fix the crash, however, I need to be able to have the file saved within an easily retrievable spot in the android file system so I can add them as email attachments.

Comment: The file is saved in the applications internal folder. For ex. /data/data/com.app.package/files. You can read the file usinf openFileInput("samplefile.txt").

Comment: How would I instead save it to the sd card, if openFileOutput cannot do it?